# Error appears when trying watson assistant advance tutorial

Tags: ibm-watson

http://advance-web-studio.com/watson/Watson_Machine_Learning.jpg

Why if I type : "Play Music" it keeps showing #goodbye intent? Earlier accidentally I change the combo box from #turn_on to #goodbye. Now, if I change it back it shows error.

Also, why there is no text response like "What kind of Music would like to hear?"

This is another picture:  http://advance-web-studio.com/watson/Watson_Machine_Learning2.jpg

I don't know if the JSON file helps at all:
This is the workspace: http://www.advance-web-studio.com/watson/workspace-a0fa3174-8fd6-460a-884b-165a9f775b07.json

This is taken from: https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/conversation/tutorial.html#tutorial

Answer (score 0):

About the first problem, you have "Play Music" as an example to the intent "goodbye" and to the intent "turn_on", thats why sometimes you are getting the wrong intent.

Go to the intents tab, select the intent "goodbye" and remove the example from there. Everything you add from the combo-box on the "try out", goes to the intent examples.

On the second error, you condition "#turn_on" is on the node name, it needs to be on node condition, "If bot recognizes:"